Fix position of images across slides below text of variable length
I have created the two images shown below, which have the same height but different widths. Since they are meant to be seen sequentially to highlight different aspects of the dataframe, I want to fix the position of the image in subsequent slides, so that the main dataframe (the rectangle) does not move when transitioning to the next slide. In addition, the images are proceeded by some bullet points of variable length. I have tried to achieve this with the code below, but unfortunately it does not work, as the main dataframes are not anchored to the same point. Can someone help me understand how to fix this please?
\documentclass[8pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}

% Margins
\setbeamersize{text margin left=6mm, text margin right=6mm} 

% Mathematics general
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm, bbm, mathtools}

% Style of bullet points
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[ball]

% Images
\usepackage{graphicx, float, adjustbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    
      \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}
        \only<1>{
          Sometext
          \begin{itemize}
            \item Sometext
            \item Sometext
            \item Sometext
          \end{itemize}
          \vfill
          \includegraphics[height=6cm]{illustration-1.pdf}
        }
        \only<2>{
          Sometext
          \begin{itemize}
            \item $\mathbbm{1} \left\{ \widehat{S}_{i,\tau(t),R}\leq \widehat{S}_{\tau(t),R}^{p(1)} \right\}$ 
          \end{itemize}
          \vfill
          \includegraphics[height=6cm]{illustration-2.pdf}
        }
      \end{overlayarea}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}



See how the code leaves different white spaces at the bottom of the images. Ideally, I would like to specify a small white space (common to the two slides) below the image and fix the height of the image, so that there is a variable space between the end of the text and the top of the image.



Can you please make a small test document which we can compile?

Done. I also added the screenshots of the output.

Instead of figuring out the correct height for your overlayareas, it seems easier to use a [s]tretchable frame. This way you can simultaneously top align your text and bottom align the image:
\documentclass[8pt, notheorems]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}

% Margins
\setbeamersize{text margin left=6mm, text margin right=6mm} 

% Mathematics general
\usepackage{
%amsmath, amssymb, 
bm, bbm, mathtools}

% Style of bullet points
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[ball]

% Images
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[s]
    \frametitle{Title}
        \only<1>{%
          Sometext
          \begin{itemize}
            \item Sometext
            \item Sometext
            \item Sometext
          \end{itemize}
        }%
        \only<2>{%
          Sometext
          \begin{itemize}
            \item $\mathbbm{1} \left\{ \widehat{S}_{i,\tau(t),R}\leq \widehat{S}_{\tau(t),R}^{p(1)} \right\}$ 
          \end{itemize}
        }%
      \vfill
      
      \includegraphics<1>[height=6cm]{O9QYvhE1}%
      \includegraphics<2>[height=6cm]{Tp8iiEJj}%
      \vskip0.6cm
    \end{frame}

\end{document}



The code worked perfectly and the extremely detailed answer was equally perfect. Thank you.

@NC520 You're welcome!
